Why isn't my buildfile able to find a java class?
I'm trying to make a buildfile for a java class with a main method which uses command line arguments. But the run-target of the buildfile isn't able to find the classe even though the path should be correct.
This is the code of the buildfile:
<project name = "." default = "run" basedir =".">
    <description>
        BuildFile for APPDrawEvent.java
    </description>
    <property name = "build.dir" location = "./build"/>
    <property name = "src.dir" location = "./src"/>
    <property name = "doc.dir" location ="./documentation"/>
    <property name = "file" location ="AppDrawEvent"/>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir = "${doc.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name ="compile"  depends = "init">
        <javac srcdir = "${src.dir}"
            destdir = "${build.dir}"
            includeantruntime = "false"/>
    </target>

    <target name = "document" depends = "compile">
        <javadoc destdir = "${doc.dir}">
            <fileset dir = "${src.dir}" />
        </javadoc>
           
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="compile, input-runargs" description="run the project">
    <java sourcefile="${build.dir}/AppDrawEvent" fork = "true">
         <arg line="${args}"/>
     </java>
    </target>

    <target name="input-runargs" unless="args" description="prompts for command line arguments if necessary">
        <input addProperty="args" message="Type the desired command line arguments: "/>
    </target>
</project>

The AppDrawEvent class is in the ./build directory which can be found in the directory the buildfile is located in. The error-message is the following:
[java] error: Main class C:[...]\uebung04\build\AppDrawEvent could not be found or loaded
I had to translate the error message because my system is set in German. I hope it still makes sense. I've also replaced the directories above the one where build.xml is located (uebung04) with "[...]".
All the other targets except the run-target are executing as they should be. The directory path should also be correct and the files are compilated into the build-directory, so I'm at a loss why my buildfile doesn't find the class.
As asked I have now run ant -d compile run. It generated the following output:
PS C:[...]\uebung04> ant -d compile run
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.14 compiled on August 16 2023
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: C:[...]\uebung04\build.xml
Adding reference: ant.PropertyHelper
Detected Java version: 21 in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21
Detected OS: Windows 11
Adding reference: ant.ComponentHelper
Setting ro project property: ant.file -> C:[...]\uebung04\build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type -> file
Setting ro project property: ant.project.invoked-targets -> compile,run
Adding reference: ant.projectHelper
Adding reference: ant.parsing.context
Adding reference: ant.targets
parsing buildfile C:[...]\uebung04\build.xml with URI = file:/C:[...]/uebung04/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.project.name -> .
Adding reference: .
Setting ro project property: ant.project.default-target -> run
Setting ro project property: ant.file.. -> C:[...]\uebung04\build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type.. -> file
Project base dir set to: C:[...]\uebung04
 +Target:
 +Target: init
 +Target: compile
 +Target: document
 +Target: run
 +Target: input-runargs
Adding reference: ant.LocalProperties
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Setting project property: build.dir -> C:[...]\uebung04\build
Setting project property: src.dir -> C:[...]\uebung04\src
Setting project property: doc.dir -> C:[...]\uebung04\documentation
Setting project property: file -> C:[...]\uebung04\AppDrawEvent
Setting ro project property: ant.project.invoked-targets -> compile,run
Attempting to create object of type org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor
Adding reference: ant.executor
Build sequence for target(s) `compile' is [init, compile]
Complete build sequence is [init, compile, document, input-runargs, run, ]

init:
    [mkdir] Skipping C:[...]\uebung04\build because it already exists.
    [mkdir] Skipping C:[...]\uebung04\documentation because it already exists.

compile:
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:[...]\uebung04\src with patternSet{ includes: [] excludes: [] }
    [javac] AppDrawEvent.java omitted as C:[...]\uebung04\build\AppDrawEvent.class is up to date.
Build sequence for target(s) `run' is [init, compile, input-runargs, run]
Complete build sequence is [init, compile, input-runargs, run, document, ]

init:
    [mkdir] Skipping C:[...]\uebung04\build because it already exists.
    [mkdir] Skipping C:[...]\uebung04\documentation because it already exists.

compile:
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:[...]\uebung04\src with patternSet{ includes: [] excludes: [] }
    [javac] AppDrawEvent.java omitted as C:[...]\uebung04\build\AppDrawEvent.class is up to date.

input-runargs:
    [input] Type the desired command line arguments:
a
Setting project property: args -> a

run:
     [java] Executing 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
     [java] 'C:[...]\uebung04\build\AppDrawEvent'
     [java] 'a'
     [java]
     [java] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [java] not part of the command.
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
'C:[...]\uebung04\build\AppDrawEvent'
'a'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
     [java] Error: Main class C:[...]\uebung04\build\AppDrawEvent konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
     [java] Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:[...]\uebung04\build\AppDrawEvent
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
PS C:[...]/uebung04>

Again, I have replaced the directory path above uebung04 with "[...]" because that part would display my full name and translated the error message to english.

Please edoiot your question and add the exact error message.

I've added the error message now. I hope it resembles roughly what the error message in English would be as my system is set in German

Please post full output of ant -d compile run

<property name = "file" location ="AppDrawEvent.class"/> with ,class/.jar maybe? My last usage of ant is before 10 years, maven (or gradle) seems a better solution, as ant leads to temptation in programming the build.

I have already tried using the file property with ".class". It still produces the same error message. That's why, for now, I just wrote the file name into the java task but that also doesn't work.

I just tried starting the class from the uebung04 directory manually via the terminal which produces the same error message. So, I guess it might not be a problem with ant but a general problem with my computer/terminal, though I still have no idea what causes the error. The class has a main method and is located in the sub-directory I specified.

Your java task is wrong. Try this instead: <target name="run" depends="compile, input-runargs" description="run the project">    <java classname="AppDrawEvent" fork="true" failonerror="true">        <classpath path="${build.dir}"/>    </java></target> That assumes your main class is in the default ('no') package

It finally worked. Thank you so much :D I've been trying to get this file to work for hours now.

Do you really need to use ant? It is very rarely used for new projects.

I assume that your file name is AppDrawEvent.java.
Use
   <property name = "file" location ="AppDrawEvent.java"/>

PS: ant is ancient system, dinosaurus like me almost extinct, soon no one would be able to help you :) So think about stepping into 21th century, it not as scary as you think.
